# Labels remain when polygon is hidden

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the Autodesk Viewer with the Edit2D extension and working on labels.  The strange thing is that labels seem to leave a 'residue' when the polygon is hidden.

I have several polygons on the layer and the ability for the user to hide them.  When they do that, this code does the hiding:

```
export function setRegionVisibility(
  editor: Autodesk.Extensions.Edit2D,
  region: RegionData,
  geometry: SpaceGeometry,
  visible: boolean
): void {
  const shape = editor.defaultContext.layer.shapes.find(
    (s) => s.id === region.itemIds[0]
  );
  if (shape == null) {
    return;
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  shape.visible = visible;
  editor.defaultContext.layer.update();
  return;
}
```

However, when a polygon is hidden, the label that was for it remains on the view.  When I re-show the shape it gets a NEW label which moves with it, but the old one remains on the view and just stays in a static location regardless of the zooming or panning of the view.

I tried to manually hide it or remove it but nothing seems to work.  This is how I tried to do that:

```
export function setRegionVisibility(
  editor: Autodesk.Extensions.Edit2D,
  region: RegionData,
  geometry: SpaceGeometry,
  // @ts-ignore
  tagRule: Autodesk.Edit2D.ShapeLabelRule | undefined,
  visible: boolean
): void {
  const shape = editor.defaultContext.layer.shapes.find(
    (s) => s.id === region.itemIds[0]
  );
  if (shape == null) {
    return;
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  shape.visible = visible;
  let label: any;
  for (let labelsKey in tagRule.labels) {
    if (labelsKey === shape.id.toString()) {
      label = tagRule.labels[labelsKey];
    }
    console.log(tagRule.labels);
  }
  if (label != null) {
    label.visible = visible;
    console.log(label);
    label.dtor();
    label.update();
    label.layer.update();
  }
  editor.defaultContext.layer.update();
  return;
}
```

Any idea how to make that ghost go away?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way of toggling the visibility of the Edit2D shapes, so this will be tricky, but let me ask the engineering team.

Comment: Here's the feedback from the team: shape labels can be temporarily hidden by setting their `valueValid` property to `false`.
However, it seems that only the label is linked to the shape and not the other way around.
In order to get the label for that shape you can find it in the list of gizmo shapes.
Something like this:
`edit2d.defaultContext.layer.canvasGizmos.find(entry => entry?.shape?.id === poly.id)`

Comment: In order to to update the the label appearance you'd need to call `label.update()`.

Comment: I did that though... Look at the second block of code.  It null checks the label (and I verified that it gets through that null check via the console log inside that block).  That bock sets it to not visible and calls the update, etc. and it still doesn't work.